# Add Command in Ellipse Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I implement MVVM in my project (Windows store app) using ICommand (because I don't understand the RelayCommand). How to bind command to Ellipse like button?

As far I know I can accomplish this by 2 method:

1/ Make Ellipse as Button Template then bind the command to button. I tried this method but it only works when I click the border of Ellipse.

2/ Add command to event PointerPressed of Ellipse which I don't have a clue.

```
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding GenerateLevel}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Height="{Binding CircleDiameter[0]}" Width="{Binding CircleDiameter[0]}" Stroke="Crimson" StrokeThickness="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: ICommand is an interface and RelayCommand is one of the possible implementors. You have to create an instance of a class implementing the ICommand interface or you cannot use it at all.

Comment: I succeed bind the command to normal button @SirRufo. My question is how to bind the command to the Ellipse like button?

Comment: Please show the code of the Ellipse Button template

Comment: Question updated @SirRufo

Comment: Remove all the template parts `Button.Template` / `ControlTemplate` and leave just the ellipse inside the button.

Comment: That works amazing! Thanks @SirRufo. Can you post the answer?